# Prevent image inside a flex container from stretching in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It looks fine in firefox, but in chrome my images are all stretched crazy tall. I've tried all sorts of solutions I've found online like setting img's min-height to 0 or adding a height:auto to the code, nothing seems to help. is flexbox in chrome just broken?

here's the JSFiddle with my code.

https://jsfiddle.net/xyk537n1/

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.media li,
#sitetitle {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease
}

#sitetitle:hover,
.media li:hover {
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit
}

html,
body {
  background: url('img/bg02.jpg') #233 top;
  /* min-width:1310px; */
  font: normal .95em 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  color: #233
}

h2,
figcaption {
  font: normal 1.65em 'Dosis', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif
}

abbr {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #233;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

article {
  max-width: 100%
}

#sitetitle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 .2em .3em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: bold calc(2.1em + 1.5vw) 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
}

#sitetitle:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000
}

.clear {
  clear: both
}

.wrapper {
  padding: .5em;
  background: rgb(34, 51, 51);
  background: rgba(34, 51, 51, 0.8)
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.wrapper>* {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.column {
  max-width: 100%
}

.block {
  background: #bbb;
  padding: .5em;
}

.block {
  margin: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #233;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100
}

.block {
  box-shadow: 0 7px 5px -5px black
}

.block img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}

.media li {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative
}

.media li {
  max-width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: .5em
}

.media a {
  display: flex;
}

.media li:hover {
  background: #fff
}

.media li a strong {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  background: #233;
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: .5em;
  font-size: calc(.5em + 1.5vw);
}

.media {
  border-top: 6px solid #7d1
}

.media a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #233
}

#footer {
  padding: 1.5em 1em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="/" id="sitetitle">testsite.com</a>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="column">
    <ul class="block media">
      <li>
        <a href="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" data-lightbox="foliogal" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" /><strong>Render > BMD Company logo > 2013</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" data-lightbox="foliogal" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" /><strong>Render > Wireless internet ad > 2011</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://i.imgur.com/5YFSgau.jpg" data-lightbox="foliogal" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5YFSgau.jpg" /><strong>Graphic > Business ad > 2012</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://i.imgur.com/5YFSgau.jpg" data-lightbox="foliogal" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/5YFSgau.jpg" /><strong>Graphic > Business ad > 2012</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" data-lightbox="foliogal" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" /><strong>Render > NukaCola cooler model > 2010</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" data-lightbox="foliogal" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" /><strong>WIP > Goggles/Headphones > 2010</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" data-lightbox="foliogal" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" /><strong>WIP > Goggles/Headphones > 2010</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" data-lightbox="foliogal" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ufW4BAE.jpg" /><strong>Screenshot > jb_orange > 2009</strong></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </article>
  <p id="footer">footerfooterfooter foooter fooooooooooter.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial setting on a flex container is `align-items: stretch`.

Try switching the value to `flex-start`.

Chrome and FF seem to handle that differently.

```
.media a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; /* NEW */
}
```

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xyk537n1/1/)